# Best practices for storing translatable android strings in DB

Tags: android, mongodb, android-widget, persistent-storage

In one of my app's forms I have an spinner populated from an string array android resource, thus translation is managed creating additional XML files in the android app. The form data get persisted in a mongodb through an API and I also have full control over both if it's relevant.

The app will launch in 5 languages (it may grow later) so I can get 5 different 'versions' of the same string but I want the strings to be seen in the app in the language the app is in that moment (independently of the language it was stored in).

If possible, I would like to achieve this using native android translation capabilities, ie, shipping 5 XML files in the app, one for each language. 
I also want to have the server code as dumb as possible.

As of now, I can only think of storing an index in the db and then using a switch/case loop, presenting the data in the app view. I don't like this at all because the possible options will have to be hardcoded and any change would mean a new app version.

What's the best practice on this?

Comment: No idea what are You trying to archive. 5 languages in 5 xmls - ok, dynamically  switching language - sure - change locale and then configuration, update configuration. But what does DB has to do with it?

Comment: If you remove db from the equation, there's no problem at all. But if I want store the data from the form in a DB, problems arise. If I have the app in English and the text in the spinner is what is stored, when other people retrieve it and have the app in Spanish, that text will still be in English

Comment: Oh, so You want to translate contents of user input? Something like having in xml @string/work => 'work' and in xml-de @string/work => 'arbeit', and spinner adjust? Well this should work without a problem, just generate Your spinner with R.string.work and locale will take care of change. Unless user inputs something that has not been translated - then Android fallbacks to default.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, I understand that your actual problem is storing a spinner value in the database.

As you're saying in your question, you shouldn't store the string of the spinner but an integer representing that value. And then use your spinner with a List< Integer > instead of a List< String >.

An alternative to that int index with no meaning is an enumeration :

```
public enum SpinnerValues {
    EXAMPLE_1(R.string.example1_string),
    EXAMPLE_2(R.string.example2_string),
    EXAMPLE_3(R.string.example3_string);

    private int mStringResId;

    private SpinnerValues(int stringResourceId) {
        mStringResId = stringResourceId;
    }

    public int getStringResId() {
        return mStringResId;
    }
}
```

In that case, your spinner data would be List< SpinnerValue > and you would store your enum in database either with the ordinal or with the string representation of the enum (I would recommand the string value so that changing order of the enum values wouldn't break your database).

Comment: This resolves the problem of saving spinner's value in a way I like. But it's still open the question if this is the best (or recommended) way of doing this. Because this aproach has a fundamental flaw I hadn't thought when I asked the question: once the app is released in the wild, if version A, adds string EXAMPLE_4, users who are still using version A-1 will fetch the data from API but won't have the resource translation available. So this may imply that translations may be best placed in the DB than in an string resource.

Comment: I disagree. Storing translatable strings in the database would mean that you have to handle the localisation with your own means, without using the Android framework resources.
The use case you're mentionning can not happen if you're storing your data locally. If you add a new value in your spinner, you'd have to re-publish your app with the new enum value. No old user could have it in its database.

Comment: If you're retrieving your form data from a webservice as you suggest, it may be a little different but you can safely assume that your user will have the same version of the application on all devices (if not, just display a default value). Or you can version your web API.

Comment: Of course, but I'm storing the data on a REST service and the most common use case is one user creates the info and many users get it. That exacerbates the problem of having different client versions.

Comment: I don't get it, how do you translate the spinner values if it's created by users?

Comment: The spinner values are fixed (for a particular version of the app), let's say for example is category info. If in version n, I decide to add one aditional category, I can add all the translations at the same time. The users will create items with all the available categories but users at version n-1 won't have a translation available.

Comment: Indeed, if it's shared by all users, you can have some issues with people that don't update...
In your case, you might be better off not storing the values locally but handle all of your spinner localisation server-side. That's too bad cause Android localisation is very efficient but it's made for static text...